# Volver a commit anterior - Git/Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, github, git-commit

Tengo un programa que estoy haciendo en eclipse con Java. Hice varias modificaciones en distintas clases (refractor > rename) las cuales quiero deshacer, dichas modificaciones no han sido comitteadas ni añadidas con "git add ." . Tengo commit anterior a los cambios, pero por algún motivo el programa no vuelve a la versión anterior.
He intentado git checkout (id commit) .; git reset --hard ; git reset --hard HEAD~3.
Necesito ayuda.

Comment: `git reset --hard` es el metodo mas radical para hacer esta operación. Eso no debe fallar. Luego de correr ese comando, git te va a dejar los archivos como en la revisión que le están indicando. Sería bueno que coloques la salida de estos comandos en una secuencia como parte de la pregunta (en texto, no como imagen): `git status; git reset --hard la-revision; git status`

Comment: Al final era el comando  'git restore'